# Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo returns empty string

Tags: c#, winforms, environment-variables

I'm using following code to find out the Send to folder location.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo)
```

Although It works fine on all of my machines. It comes up empty for some of the users. What is the reason behind this and How can I find the proper Send to location when it comes up empty?

Comment: There are any differences in the operating system?

Comment: @Steve Users who reported this also uses Windows 10.